# description max limit in facebook sharer

Tags: facebook, limit, max, facebook-sharer

Does anyone know the maximum limit of description field in facebook feed sharer?
It seems to be 100 characters but I can't find any documentation says about max length od description field.

Answer (score 3):

It's as of today 100 characters for the title and 108 characters for the description. That's what shows up in the preview when you post a link to Facebook. The actual sharer.php page however will show more of the description.

Answer (score 2):

There is a related question here:

[Facebook open graph meta tags maximum content length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914476/facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-maximum-content-length)

(since open graph tags are used by the sharer)

It seems the answer is that there isn't a hard limit, but Facebook will truncate it as needed, which is different depending where it is used; and that the limit for news feeds changes all the time.